# Whats a DBMS... Confused

Tags: mysql, database, server, client, workbench

I'm on a big doubt, Whats really a DBMS. Is it the Client who manages the database server? Or is it the Server...
Is it Mysql Workbench the DBMS or is it the MYSQL Server.

Please if you could help,Thanks!

Comment: The DBMS is the ['thing which exposes the database'](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database) - the server (or in-process interface) that accepts and processes commands and yields results. In the case of MySQL it would be the mysqld daemon/server process. The MySQL workbench UI front-end (or the MySQL command-line client) *connects* to the MySQL DBMS to issue queries.

Comment: In this case which one will be the DBMS, mysql workbench or mysql server? Explain why?

Answer (score 1):

DBMS Stands for Database Management System. Which by name clears that it is a system, which is made for managing Database.

A Database is the collection of Data stored in the Organised way.

Now, ways of managing Data is what DBMS is all about.

Now, let us understand **What mySQL is**.

MySQL is a database management system, which has some of its rule set to manage data.

**Mysql Workbench** is and IDE or a tool by which we can perform queries on the actual DBMS. Other than Mysql Workbench, you can even use CommandLine tool for MySQL to do so.

One other thing comes is SQL. SQL is Structured Query Language, which the DBMS has implemented into its rule set to query the Database.

Hope this helps.

Regards.

Answer (score 0):

DBMS is general purpose software which helps us create a database and modify the database. The data which is stored is known as database. DBMS+database=Database System